# Simple C# mistake

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
  class Module1
  {
    static void Main()
    {
            int i;
            int j;
            int[,] matriceFoglio;
            string stringa = "";

            for (i = 1; (i <= 11); i++)
            {
                stringa = "";

                for (j = 1; (j <= 11); j++)
                {
                    matriceFoglio(i, j) = 0;
                    stringa = (stringa + matriceFoglio[i,j]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(stringa);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            //  disegno l'albero di natale
            matriceFoglio[1, 5] = 1;
            matriceFoglio[2, 4] = 1;
            matriceFoglio[2, 5] = 1;
            matriceFoglio[2, 6] = 1;
            matriceFoglio[3, 3] = 1;
            matriceFoglio[3, 4] = 1;
            matriceFoglio[3, 5] = 1;
            matriceFoglio[3, 6] = 1;
            matriceFoglio[3, 7] = 1;
            matriceFoglio[4, 5] = 1;
            matriceFoglio[5, 5] = 1;

            //  disegno l'albero
            Console.WriteLine("");

            for (i = 1; (i <= 11); i++)
            {
                stringa = "";

                for (j = 1; (j <= 11); j++)
                {
                    stringa = (stringa + matriceFoglio[i, j]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(stringa);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

In the for loop the compiler throws this error:

> Method name expected and Use of unassigned local variable 'matriceFoglio'.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Change `int[,] matriceFoglio` to `int[,] matriceFoglio = new int[1000,1000];`. "Why 1000?", no reason.

Answer (score 2):

I know other people have pointed this out, but just to add a few things here. There are two errors here, both of which are pretty much what the compiler said they are. First:

```
matriceFoglio(i, j) = 0;
```

This isn't the correct syntax - that's syntax for a method call, not array assignment. That's why the compiler expects this to be a method name. This should actually be

```
matriceFoglio[i, j] = 0;
```

Also, `int[,] matriceFoglio;` isn't initialized when you use it, so the compiler's absolutely correct here too. You have to create the array in advance of using it - you can't just start assigning to it. To understand why this is, consider first how arrays are actually implemented: suppose you were to implement an array of size 10. When you initialize the array, the runtime will "lay out" 10 consecutive locations in memory and store the location of the first item. The array index is an offset from the initial address - that's why the first item is item 0 (there's no offset, by definition the first item is at the pointer location). However, if you wanted to access the fifth item in the array, its location is `(address of the first item) + (32 * 4)` (assuming 32-bit addresses). That's why you can do constant-time random access - finding an arbitrary location is just pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to initialize your array (size 10x10 in this example):

```
int[,] matriceFoglio = new int[10, 10];
```

Secondly, use square brackets to access array instead of curly brackets:

```
// replace matriceFoglio(i, j) = 0; with
matriceFoglio[i, j] = 0;
```

**UPDATE**
Another error, I guess, is related to incorrect loop indexes, basicaly there is no element with index `11` (I assume that array size is 10x10). It should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i have do it and it's correct but if i launch debug there is another error.

Comment: @MatteoCollimedaglia I've updated my answer, but I'm only guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize matriceFoglio using new:

```
matriceFoglio = new int[10,10];
```

Also when you assign a value to matriceFoglio, you need to use brackets [] instead of parentheses such as

```
matriceFoglio[i,j] = 0;
```